# Any lexicon for age, gender and ocuupation to extract from tweets in R?

Tags: r, twitter, extract

There is lexicon available for sentiment.Likewise any lexicon for age, gender, and occupation that can be used in R and extract relevant demographics data from tweets.

Any function related to gender, age and occupation in R.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some reading, it is not a simple plug and play thing yet, but there is solid work for Facebook & Twitter demographic work.
This is the link to the ZIP of the lexicon:

[2004 Age & Gender Lexica](http://wwbp.org/downloads/public_data/emnlp2014_ageGenderLexica.zip)

Here is a link to a paper (it is academic and heavy) it explains the limit and scope of accuracy for this lexicon:

[Paper on this lexicon and how it was developed and tested](http://wwbp.org/papers/emnlp2014_developingLexica.pdf)

Here is some guidance in getting started with this type of analysis:

[Age Gender Tutorial Video](http://lexhub.org/tutorials.html)

ANd some information on how to bring it together with other demography including occupation.

[Demography and Twitter](http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~danielpr/jobs-slides.pdf)

It is not a simple ANSWER, because we are not yet at the stage with this yet. But this should get you going!

Comment: Thanks, and I have been through this resources and paper related to age and gender lexicon. But didn't get anything useful to be used in my work.

Comment: What differences are you looking for in the results?

Comment: I collected tweets related to an event not from a user timeline.So each tweet belongs to a particular user. Can I apply this lexicon to tweets??

Comment: You can. If you read through the paper with it, the reliability varies with the number of tweets from an individual. But you could put it in a dataframe and group_by user and then summarize for counts to see how unique the tweeters are. If you have duplicates from a person, then you might be able to make some cautious estimates.